# Embed iphone body in website

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I am starting out in html5 and javascript, and i've seen this trick done in a number of websites. Is it possible to show in a website a picture of a iphone or android device,and within that device show content from your iphone or android app, with a time interval(that is show 7 seven images in a time reel). I've seen this done with a axure inline frame, but is it possible to do it with javascript, css or html5?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the 'content' a fixed size and put an image of an iPhone with a transparent screen on top of that.